# How to use layoutinflator to add views at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts: main.xml and buttonpanel.xml.  In buttonpanel.xml, in main linearlayout I set gravity to bottom.  Now i am trying to add the buttonpanel layout using the following code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlinearlayout);
LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonpanel,null);
layout.addView(view);
```

My problem is that the panel is added to the top though i have set gravity to bottom in buttonpanel.xml.  If I add buttonpanel.xml to main.xml using include it works fine.

Can anyone help me what is the wrong with my code?

Comment: Check this for a more detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/making-sense-of-layoutinflater

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making sense of LayoutInflater](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/making-sense-of-layoutinflater)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have had problems with layout parameters being dropped when inflating views in the way that you are doing it. If I use a slightly different call to `inflate` my layout parameters are respected:

```
parent_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonpanel, parent);
```

Or in my case, when the parent did not support adding views to it:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonpanel, parent, false);
```

Perhaps this will solve your problem as well.

EDIT: Different views are returned depending on what parameters are given. [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Comment: as you said parent didnt support adding views to it.so view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonpanel, parent, false); solves my problem.thankx

Comment: Helped me, too, but I had to call parent.addView(view); to add the view to the layout

Comment: I do it this way and my view still aligns to top :/

Comment: What do you mean by not support ? how to determine parent not support addView

Answer (score 0):

you can use childview index for setting it. i think it will help you.try another method for addview which include childindex