# Android Fragment does not respect match_parent as height

Tags: android, center, android-linearlayout, fragment, android-framelayout

Sorry for the huge code dump, but I'm truly lost.

**MyActivity.java onCreate**:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_singlepane_empty);
mFragment = new PlacesFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.root_container, mFragment)
                    .commit();
```

**PlacesFragment.java onCreateView**:

```
mRootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, null);
return mRootView;
```

**Notes**: `mRootView` is a `ViewGroup` global, no problem about it, I believe. `PlacesFragment` is a `ListFragment`.

Layouts:

**activity_singlepane_empty.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00f">
    <include layout="@layout/actionbar"/>

    <!-- FRAGMENTS COME HERE! See match_parent above -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_content.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listContainer"
        android:background="#990"
        >
    
        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
        
        <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                android:text="@string/no_data_suggest_connection"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Problem:** as you can see, the expected behavior would be to have the empty `TextView` above to appear centered on the screen. On the design preview in Eclipse, it is OK. Only when added to `root_view` as a fragment the `FrameLayout` won't fill the whole screen.

`root_container` is blue, and `FrameLayout` is yellowish, see below for debug purposes. ***Shouldn't the yellow pane fill the whole screen?!?!?!?***

[image]

Comment: If you use ScrollView checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211338/view-inside-scrollview-doesnt-take-all-place

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I had the same problem and think it happens when you inflate the layout in the Fragment's onCreateView with null, like you did here:

```
mRootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, null);
```

Instead you have to do this:

```
mRootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content,container, false);
```

Where container is the Viewgroup. At least, that solved the problem for me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)

Answer accepted. Thank you.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/making-sense-of-layoutinflater

Comment: What ViewGroup is container? root_container from activity_singlepane_empty.xml?

Answer (score 6):

For some reason the FrameLayout does not get its layout from the XML.

I need to set it also in code (Fragment's onCreateView):

```
mRootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, null);
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.listContainer);
fl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
return mRootView;
```

Comment: This is an old answer. Since then, I switched the acceptance mark to Norman's answer. Of course this answer provides more flexibility, but I'm glad to accept his since this question clearly warranted a solution for easy-of-use.

Answer (score 5):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/screen_main_fragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I had to change layout_height="wrap_content" to "match_parent"to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did that was to create a transparent image in xml code, make the fragment a relative layout and make`layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in the `ImageView`, this way the image sticks to the bottom and makes the fragment fill the parent

Code Here:

temp_transparent.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:thickness="0dp"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#00000000"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="270"/>
```

fragment_my_invites.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/my_invites_fragment"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#ffffff">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_invites"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/transparent_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/list_invites"
    android:src="@drawable/temp_transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem & i tried many things but none of them worked.

**What problem faced?**

I had `<FrameLayout>` inside `<ScrollView>` which height is set to 0dp which causes the problem.

```
<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:background="@color/white"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myToolbar">

      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myToolbar" />
</ScrollView>
```

To make it working change all the outer containing views to **match_parent**

Comment: How could this be the same problem davidcesarino had, if he didn't set any height to 0dp?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to the Parent Layout will solve that problem,

`android:fillViewport="true"`