# View inside ScrollView doesn't take all place

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I have a RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView.
My RelativeLayout has `android:layout_height="match_parent"` but the view doesn't take the entire size, it's like a wrap_content.

Is there a way to have the real fill_parent/match_parent behavior ?

My layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/top" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/headerbig" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dashboard01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dashboard02"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dashboard01"
            android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dashboard02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dashboard02" />

             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dashboard03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dashboard02"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dashboard03"
            android:visibility="visible" />
         </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/bar" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 510, accepted):

Try adding `android:fillViewport="true"`to your ScrollView

> remember that `android:layout_height=”fill_parent”` means “set the height to the height of the parent.” This is obviously not what you want when using a `ScrollView`. After all, the `ScrollView` would become useless if its content was always as tall as itself. To work around this, you need to use the ScrollView attribute called `android:fillViewport`. When set to true, this attribute causes the scroll view’s child to expand to the height of the `ScrollView` if needed. When the child is taller than the `ScrollView`, the attribute has no effect.

http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

Comment: The same is for HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, make sure you set the attribute on the ScrollView, not the child!

Answer (score 17):

Just add android:fillViewport="true"  in yout xml layout in Scrollview

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

<!--define views here-->


</ScrollView>
```