# Set ListView item height

Tags: android, listview

this should be a very easy thing to do, but it looks like it's very tricky.
In my code I have this ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/sums_list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:dividerHeight="0dp"></ListView>
```

That is populated with an ArrayAdapter that uses this view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cdpb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ale.android.brainfitness"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Why isn't the item 55dp high?

Thanks everybody

Comment: Why `android:layout_height="0dp"` ?

Comment: What is actually happening? Are you seeing the items but with the wrong height? Are you seeing no items? There isn't anything obviously wrong with what you've posted, but seeing your adapter and knowing what you're seeing now would be helpful.

Comment: @Secator the 0dp defines whether the weight will be applied to height or width. so in this example the weight of 1 will be applied to height as that is set to 0dp.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

How are you inflating the view?

If you are setting 'parent' parameter to null like below, then layout parameters are ignored.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ...
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, null);
  …

  return v;
}
```

Passing 'parent' to inflate should work as you expect.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ...
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, parent);
  …

  return v;
}
```

This explains it in detail: [Why does LayoutInflater ignore the layout_width and layout_height layout parameters I've specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/making-sense-of-layoutinflater)

To avoid getting `UnsupportedOperationException`, you can add `false` as an input parameter to the `inflator`. Example:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, parent, false)
```

Comment: Thanks Amol, I could not make sense of LayoutInflater, now it's all clear. I could make it work and most of all, I understood why it's working like that. Thanks a lot

Comment: if you get unsupported operation: check out this: LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mDisplayWidth / 3, 30);
   convertView.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: @Amol Brid, i get error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
`

Comment: to avoid @AlanLai's issue, add the parameter `false` to the method `inflate`

Comment: @Alan Lai like this:  `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, parent,false);`

Comment: @Amol Brid i got too error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Comment: Thank you for mentioning "false" parameter of inflater. This little change solved my problem!

Answer (score 9):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ...
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, parent,false);
  …

  return v;
}
```

just pass boolean value to the method so that it add the yourrowlayout to the listview
and it will not give error futher like  error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

and add yourLayout which u wants to populate through Adapter

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cdpb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ale.android.brainfitness"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

it works for me and i think it may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/main_color">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_left_menu"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tx_left_menu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

in the adapter set the parent as described above

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ...
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, parent,false);
  …

  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

if (CONDITION) {
    holder.wholeLayout.getLayoutParams().height = 1; // visibility Gone not working && 0 height crash app.
} else {
    holder.wholeLayout.getLayoutParams().height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
}
```