# How to Adjust Listview Item on Screen Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I make App which uses Listview

main_acivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/common_bg_common"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="3sp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and costomItem is below

costomo_cell.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#cc9933"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="dummyCanvas"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
        android:background="#cc3333"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now,I want to fill Screen by One Item.
I have think to write match_parent in custom_cell.xml,but cant.

I dont want to write xxdp.
Linear1 is 2/3 size in screen size.
other content (linear2) is 1/3 size...

How I configure Custom cell layout?

--------edited---
I upload scrennshot.
black line is one Item separete.
I want to adjust on Screen Size
[image: capture]

Comment: Please check this
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439401/set-listview-item-height][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439401/set-listview-item-height

Comment: Have you created the adapter for the Listview to bind the data with your custom layout ?

Comment: do you want to fill the entire screen with only one item?

Comment: @Premsuraj I tryied this, but not working.

Comment: @Grishu yes I created CostomAdapter extends Arrayadapter,and infrate custom_cell.xml in getview()

Comment: @Drax yes, one Item of height is screen size,but number of item are 10 ~20..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyListItemView extends LinearLayout {

public MyListItemView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.costomo_cell, this);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
}
```

Now in the adapter's getView instantiate MyListItemView instance

Comment: how do use this in getView()?

Comment: Which adapter are you using?

Comment: `View item = new MyListItemView(context);`

Also make sure that the adapter has a reference to context.

Comment: I using ArrayAdapter<String>.

Comment: From your previous comment you have a CustomAdapter derived from ArrayAdapter, so you need to implement the getView method of the adapter.

Comment: ohh,amazing!!It is correct almost well, when disable TitleBar. if i use with Tab or ActionBar, can apply this layout?

Comment: I do not have off my head answer, but if MyListItemView can access the parent listview somehow, then taking the height of the listiview will give you the perfect height you want.

Answer (score 2):

I used **setLayoutParams** to do that in BaseAdapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.list_item, null);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
            getListView().getWidth(), AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
    other code...
}
```

getListView() is a wrap method, it return a ListView and I use it width as item width, hope could help you.