# Building xml relative layout programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to update/populate xml on run-time. The textViews are displayed fine but it seems like it fails position them correctly after the first item (see the else statement). Is it because `getId()` is not recognised or am I totally wrong?

```
for(int x=1; x<13; x++){
    String prompt="PROMPT_"+String.valueOf(x);
    String promptValue = myTacorCursor.getString(myTacorCursor.getColumnIndex(prompt));
    //if not empty draw a row
    if (!promptValue.equals("")){
        //insert new rows into layout
        RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
        TextView promptLabel = new TextView(this);
        promptLabel.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Large);
        promptLabel.setText(myTacorCursor.getString(myTacorCursor.getColumnIndex("PROMPT_"+String.valueOf(x))));                
        promptLabel.setId(1);
        ((RelativeLayout) myLayout).addView(promptLabel);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams1=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)promptLabel.getLayoutParams();
        mLayoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        if (i==1){
            mLayoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.textView7);
            Log.w("ID is:", String.valueOf(promptLabel.getId()));
        } else{                 
            mLayoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,promptLabel.getId());
            Log.w("ID is:", String.valueOf(promptLabel.getId()));
        }
    i++;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display:

```
(textView)LABEL xx R.id.textview7
<-- here would be the inserted columns -->
(text view) prompt 1 
(text view) prompt 2
(text view) prompt 3
... etc ...'
```

Comment: It'll be useful if you state what you want to show on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting ids dynamically is OK. Just some more attentiveness and your code works.

1. As far as you're in the `for` loop, it's better to increment index only in one place.
2. After you've changed the `LayoutParams` of the `View` you need to set it back: `promptLabel.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)`

Try this. It should work:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int BASE_ID = 1;
    private static final int ITEMS_COUNT = 13;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

        for (int index = BASE_ID; index < ITEMS_COUNT; index++) {
            String prompt = "PROMPT_" + String.valueOf(index);
            // if not empty draw a row
            // insert new rows into layout
            TextView promptLabel = new TextView(this);
            promptLabel.setTextAppearance(this,
                    android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Large);
            promptLabel.setText(prompt);
            promptLabel.setId(index);
            rootLayout.addView(promptLabel);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) promptLabel
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            if (index == BASE_ID) {
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.top);
                Log.d("ID is:", String.valueOf(index));
            } else {
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, index - 1);
                Log.d("ID is:", String.valueOf(index - 1));
            }
            promptLabel.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to construct the whole layout programatically. Define it in separate layout `xml` file and then use layout inflater to inflate it. After that add it where you want it.

I have never seen `id`s assigned programatically, but with my suggestion you can define them in the xml as usual.

PS: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5027921/1108032) is a good example explaining how to use [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Comment: I can see where you coming from and I've tried to implement it but I have the same problem as before as I want it to be as dynamic as possible. Question: If I'll use LayoutInflater would I be able override the ID of the textView on the fly or will I have to create 13 instances of the textView in the xml as there might be 1, 2 or 13 prompts.

Comment: @user2224135 Why are you aiming at using ids instead of Tags? I know you can programatically control tags.

Comment: It is for better control and data handling as I have many variations of possible layouts. See riwnodennyk answer which solved the problem. Your suggested idea works too though