# LinearLayout Pushing Items out of view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-button

I am adding button dynamically to a `LinearLayout` . The `orientation` is set to `horizontal` in the xml.I have two problems 1st the items are moving out of the view except for a few. The items need to push to the second row if they exceed the bounds. 2nd The buttons need to sit in the center of the screen with equal padding on both sides.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#F12312" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
final LinearLayout Row = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll2);
final LinearLayout TVRow = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);


final Button[] my_button = new Button[Keys.size()];
final Button[] et = new Button[Texts.size()];

for (int bt = 0; bt < Keys.size(); bt ++){
final int Index = bt;
my_button[Index] = new Button(this);
my_button[Index].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
my_button[Index].setText(Keys.get(Index));
my_button[Index].setId(Index);
my_button[Index].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: use layout inflator insted of creating dynamic view

Comment: Also must sure that in your xml file there is **RelativeLayout** and in java file you are trying to add a view in **LinearLayout**??? Check it

Comment: Edited Code. I had pasted the wrong xml code. Its supposed to be LinearLayout. Sorry my bad.

Comment: @DigveshPatel any hints on how its to be done ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/making-sense-of-layoutinflater

Comment: create two different layout if the items are moving out of the view except for a few

Comment: for the buttons set the layout_gravity for them