# Android layaout Params

Tags: android, layoutparams

I have a button with dimensions:

```
btn1.width = 100;
btn2.height = 150;
```

I used the following code to resize:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btn1.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = 200;
layoutParams.height = 300;
btn1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

When I did this:

```
int newSize = btn1.getWidth;
```

The newSize has value 100, but not 200. It resized the button well, but after the resize, `btn1.getWidth` still holds the previous value. How can I instantly get the set size?

Comment: Have you tried print something at Logs, to check if those lines were executed?

Comment: where you add this line in your code?

Comment: Add it in onWindowsFocuschange.

Comment: Are executed. If after it shows, i touch the button and print the size it returns 200. If i ask for the width after i change it it return old one, but after it return the new one!

Comment: It might depends on how you inflate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5027921/5028508

Answer (score 0):

The actual width of the `View` does not get updated immediately.

Your best bet is to cache the size when you set it.

Comment: There is not a way to update immediatly? Thats my problem, is not updating the width immediatly

Comment: @user3240604 Not really; this is the way Android is designed to handle the view updates.

Answer (score 0):

You will not directly get the height/width after setting to a view. If you want then you can get in "post" method:

```
btn1.setWidth(200);
btn1.setHeight(300)
btn1.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
               Log.i("Tag", "Width:"+ btn1.getWidth() + " Height:" + btn1.getHeight());
         }
});
```

Comment: What is a post method?

Comment: Post method will be called right after the button is resized. 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)