# Why setting "layout_width" of RelativeLayout to a fixed value in layout xml not working?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to set the width and height of a `RelativeLayout` to a fixed value. My `item_view.xml` looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abc"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And finally my generateView function in the `MainActivity.java`;

```
private void generateItemView()
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);

    RelativeLayout containerView = findViewById(R.id.container);
    containerView.addView(itemView);
}
```

And this is the result;

[image]

As you can see, this is not 100dpX100dp size.

On the other hand, if I do this programmatically it works. Here is the updated generateView function;

```
private void generateItemView()
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);

    int sizeDp = 100;
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int sizePx = Math.round(sizeDp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(sizePx, sizePx);
    itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

    RelativeLayout containerView = findViewById(R.id.container);
    containerView.addView(itemView);
}
```

[image]

And it works just fine...

My question is, why can't we use the layout_width and layout_height properties in the layout xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

> ```
> View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
> ```

When you pass `null` as the parent, then any `layout_` attributes will be ignored. In order to retain them and have them take effect, you must pass a parent.

```
View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, containerView, false);
```

Your IDE *should* warn you about this case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the parent in your call to layoutinflator.inflate: `layoutinflator.inflate(R.layout.item_view, containerview, false);`. You'll also need to re-arrange the code so this is run after you instantiate containerview.

For a more detailed answer on why this is happening, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/5027921