# I don't understand the main difference between true of false for the third parameters of inflate method

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I don't understand the main difference between **true** or **false** for the third parameters of inflate method,
any helpful examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5027921/10182897 read answer

Comment: https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/06/19/android-layoutinflater-turorial/ you can read more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose we have this very simple layout:

> view_red_square.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#FA8072" />
```

And this layout used by our main activity:

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</FrameLayout>
```

Now let's try to inflate the `view_red_square.xml` layout in `MainActivity` and understand what happens.

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val container = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.container)
        val inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_red_square, container, false)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Is the view inflated: $inflatedView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

The third boolean parameter for [`LayoutInflater.inflate`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java;l=519), as the documentation points, stands for:

> attachToRoot: Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to
> the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the
> correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

So, going back to our main activity. The `false` boolean value indicates that the view inflated shouldn't be added to the `root`, also specified in the [inflate](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java;l=519) method.

Using the above code for `MainActivity`. We can verify, with the layout inspector, that the view is not added to the container when inflating the view with `attachToRoot` set to `false`.

A solution for adding the view to our container would be to manually add the view to our view group, by using `container.addView(inflatedView)`.

[image: attach to root false with the layout inspector]

Now let's see what happens when we switch that `attachToRoot` boolean to `true`. Let's again use the layout inspector.

`val inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_red_square, container, true)`

[image: attach to root true with the layout inspector]

As you can see, the view is now added to the `root` which is our container. Therefore, we can conclude that `attachToRoot`, adds the inflated view to the given root if its value is `true`.