# ListView expanding items to fill area (not multi-level!)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using a ListView with just a few items. The items are to be vertically enlarged to fill the area given to the list view. So instead of:

```
_____
1
2
3


____
```

I want

```
_____

1
_

2
_

3
____
```

I am not sure how to do this. I looked at using getView on my Adapter, but the ViewGroup return 0 for the height, and 0 for the child count. When I make my adapter have a ListView reference, I can get the child count, but height is still 0.

I'm not sure if I need to extend ListView or ViewGroup or what I need to override.

Thanks.

---

After much digging, i found the issue is the mysterious Layout Inflater issue
[described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735847/help-for-using-layoutinflator-to-add-views-at-runtime). Once I changed it to inflate(layoutIdToInflate, parent, false);
(having been inflate(layoutIdToInflate, null); the heights started working.

Comment: This older post asks the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044595/listview-to-cover-entire-screen-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `ListView` via xml. But you can set `minHeight` for your `ListView` item layout programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I even do the minHeight calculation? I can get the count, but the height of the ListView as far as I can tell is always 0.

Comment: get the height of the `ListView` container.

Comment: It always returns 0. `        int count = mContentListView.getCount();
        int height = mContentListView.getHeight();` count =5, height = 0;

Comment: no, I meant the parent view of your `ListView`. Sorry, my English is bad). Or you can use `getMeasuredHeight()` method.