# how to add same view on runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

I want to design a view like this

[image]

its the same view repeating multiple times,i.e. when clicked on **add item** , it should add same view(on the beginning there should be only one row). I don't understand how to make one, seems I can't make such view using **RecyclerView**. Maybe I can make one using **LayoutInflater**. but how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use layoutinflator to add views at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735847/how-to-use-layoutinflator-to-add-views-at-runtime)

Comment: If your views are limited then just use a `LinearLayout` as container and use `LayoutInflater` to add view . If Views can be unlimited then you should use  `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic form with repeating form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975286/dynamic-form-with-repeating-form)

Comment: @ADM I want to add this view on click event of "add item" button. what should I use?, layout inflator or recyclerview, bcoz I only need to add one row on one click of button.

Comment: Exact answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975286/dynamic-form-with-repeating-form?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thats what is said it depends upon max items can be added . if There is no limit on max item then go with `RecyclerView` of if there is a limit lets say 10 or 20 then a `LinearLayout` will work .

Comment: @NikhilBorad its not exact answer, bcoz number of items in recyclervie is dependent on number of usernames, etc in that example. In my view, there are spinners and spinners of those has nothing to do with number of times views will repeat. views will repeat based on number of times user click on "add more" button

Comment: then I prefer to use the LayoutInflater to create a view based on your layout template, and then inject it into the view where ever you want.

Comment: check my answer if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add it by using Layout Inflator:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**In Activity:**

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_container);
                LinearLayout childLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null, false);
                childLayout.setTag(linearLayout.getChildCount() + 1); // set some Id
                linearLayout.addView(childLayout); // Adding for first time
                for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    childLayout.setTag(linearLayout.getChildCount() + 1);
                    linearLayout.addView(childLayout); //child_layout is your row layout design
                }
```

**To Retrive :**

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View childLayout = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                if (childLayout instanceof LinearLayout) {
                    //get SubViews of you child_layout and get thos value 
                    // for id int id = (int) childLayout.getTag()
                    //add the values to jsonObject
                }
            }
```

Comment: your answer makes sense, but the number of times I need to repeat this view depends on number of times user clicks. can you provide code for that?

Comment: I want to add this in OnClick event of button

Comment: Yes you can write the one function to add one layout. So call that function when ever the user click on Add button

Comment: So just putting linearLayout.addView(childLayout); in onClick will do it?

Comment: Yes it will do, Try it first then ask if you have any trouble

Comment: Sure. will let you know how it goes

Comment: and how will you get data for different layouts ? all will be having same id ?

Comment: @NaveenKumarM It worked the way it should. Thank you :)

Comment: @ABDevelopers yes, data is same for all views

Comment: Try my answer too once because it will help you getting values differently

Answer (score 0):

Well Create a Model class :

```
 public  class Product{
     int product_id;
     int product_size;
     int product_qty;

        //provide all the getter setters and constructor
         public Product(int product_id,int product_size,int product_qty){
                this.product_id = product_id;
                this.product_size = product_size;
                this.product_qty = product_qty;
         }
       }
```

Now use this arraylist inside Recyclerview Adapter :

```
ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>
```

and while clicking on add button just add dummy values in this list like :

```
   productList.add(new Product(0,0,0));
```

And inside your recyclerview adapter provide the layout of your choice

Because later if you want to set values you can easily do it with position and also while clicking on submit you can just take whole list

Comment: `class` are all small letters and Java has a dedicated naming conventions (please avoid underscores in variable names).